# filtering data with vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have loaded a data from API and displayed here with VueJS. I have users information inside `users[]` array. I also have users with two types of plan: `basic_plan` and `standard_plan`. Currently it shows all users.

Now I want to apply filters equally to this example: https://codepen.io/marn/pen/jeyXKL?editors=0010

I also got an error `filter` not defined

Filters:

```
  <input type="radio" v-model="selectedItems" value="All" /> All
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedItems" value="basic_plan" /> Basic


<ul
            v-for="(user, index) in selectedUser.data"
            :key="index"
            class="watchers divide-y divide-gray-200"
        >
            <li class="py-4">
                <div class="mx-4 flex space-x-3">
                    <span
                        class="inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-500"
                    >
                      
                    </span>
                    <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                        <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">
                            {{ user.name }}
                        </h3>
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <p class="text-sm font-medium text-indigo-500">
                                {{ user.plan }}
                            </p>
                           
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

       
    </div>
</template>

<script 
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
             selectedItems:"All"
        };
    },
    created() {
        this. users();
    },
    methods: {
        users {
            axios
                .get('api/users')
                .then(response => {
                   
                        this.users = response.data;
                   
        }
    },
computed: {
        selectedUser: function() {
        
            if(this.selectedItems ==="All"){
                return this.users
            }else{
            return this.users.data.filter(function(item) {
                console.log(item)
                return item.plan === this.selectedItems;
            });
            }
        }
    }

};
</script>
```

when All is selected vue dev tool shows this

```
selectedUser:Object //OBJECT SHOWING
data:Array[10]
links:Object
meta:Object
but when basic radio is selected vue shows this

selectedUser:Array[1]  //ARRAY SHOWING
0:Object
price:"10"
plan:"basic_planl"
```

Comment: Try to change inside `computed.selectedUser()` `return this.users.data.filter` into `return this.users.filter`, because you have already applied the data property from your response onto `this.users`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out specific users you must apply the "filter" function to the users variable like this:
`this.users.filter(...)`

With this function you then can filter the users based on their plan like this:

```
this.users.filter((user) => 
  user.plan === this.selectedItems;
});
```

For a modern approach I used an arrow function. And without using curly brackets the statement inside the function is returned by default, so that's why there is no "return" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way instead, as you are already using `v-for` in your HTML, you can conveniently filter out users without any more loops, **if you are getting value as "basic_plan" in the "user.plan" key.**

Also, I think that you should move your `v-for` to `<li>` tag instead of `<ul>` along with the validation on `<ul>` if there are no users in the array.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" v-model="selectedItems" value="All" /> All
        <input type="radio" v-model="selectedItems" value="basic_plan" /> Basic
        
        <ul v-if="selectedUser.data.length" class="watchers divide-y divide-gray-200">
            <li v-for="(user, index) in selectedUser.data" :key="index" class="py-4">
                <div v-if="filterUser(user)" class="mx-4 flex space-x-3">
                    <span class="inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-500"></span>
                    <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                        <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">
                            {{ user.name }}
                        </h3>
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <p class="text-sm font-medium text-indigo-500">
                                {{ user.plan }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
            selectedItems:"All"
        };
    },
    methods: {
        filterUser(user){
            if(this.selectedItems === 'All'){
                return true;
            }
            if(this.selectedItems === 'basic_plan'){
                return this.selectedItems === user.plan;
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```